# Counting how many times each word occures in a text

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I wanted this code to do, is read a textfile, and print how much each word occures in a percent. It *almost* works..

I can't figure out how to sort the print out from highest occurrence to least (I had it at one point when I was copy/pasting other peoples code, I think I imported collections and counter, I have no idea)

But another problem is it reads through my whole list, which is fine with smaller textfiles, but larger ones just eat up my terminal, I'd like it to only print out words once, instead of once for each instance

```
name = raw_input('Enter file:')
handle = open(name, 'r')
text = handle.read()
words = text.split()

def percent(part, whole):
   return 100 * float(part)/float(whole)

total = len(words)

counts = dict()
for word in words:
    counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) + 1

print "\n"
print"Total Words\n", total
print"\n"

for word in words:
  print word, percent(counts[word],total),"%"
```

Comment: Better to use `collections.Counter` instead of just `dict`. Like so `counts=Counter( words )`. This will be much faster and more readable than `for` loop with `dict`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. One small note for asking better questions in the future is to try to give a brief description of your problem in the title. For example for this post, a better title would be "Print words by frequency". This will make it easier for people to search for answers to their own questions in the future, and also allows people who are trying to answer see what your question is asking at a glance. Other than that, this was a really good question. You are one of the first people I've seen that use markdown properly first try.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your dictionary like this:

```
for word in counts:
    print word, counts[word]
```

This will print each key in the dictionary once.
For sorting, you should look at the built-in `sorted()` function: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: shouldn't it be `for word,count in counts.itertools()`? As is, `for word,count in counts` throws an error for me.

Comment: you're right that `for word,count in counts` doesn't work. my mistake. it should instead be `for word in counts` (iterate over keys) or `for word, count in counts.iteritems()` (iterate over both keys and values)

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem you can just Collections an OrderedDict as such:

```
sortedCounts = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(counts.items(),key=lambda t: t[1]))
```

To only print each word once:

```
for key, value in sortedCounts.iteritems():
  print key, percent(value,total),"%"
```

Hope that helps

Comment: was this supposed to sort alphabetically? cause thats what happened to me, I was trying to sort by % high to low, but it did fix output to only once

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very close to being workable; I just see a few issues that are causing your problems:

**P1:** Your code doesn't take non-word characters into account. For example, `word;`, `word.`, and `word` would all be treated as unique words.

```
text = handle.read()
words = text.split()
```

**P2:** You iterate over the *entire* list of words, which includes duplicates, instead of your unique list in `counts`. So of course you'll be printing each word multiple times.

```
for word in words:
```

**P3:** You open the file but never close it. Not exactly a problem with your code, but something to be improved. This is why using `with open(...):` syntax is generally encouraged, as it handles closing the file for you.

```
handle = open(name, 'r')
```

Here's your code with some fixes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

name = raw_input('Enter file:')

def percent(part, whole):
   return 100 * float(part)/float(whole)

# better way to open files, handles closing the file
with open(name, 'r') as handle:
    text = handle.read()

words = text.split()

# get rid of non-word characters that are messing up count
formatted = []
for w in words:
    formatted.extend(re.findall(r'\w+', w))

total = len(formatted)

counts = dict()
for word in formatted:
    counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) + 1

print "\n"
print"Total Words\n", total
print"\n"

# iterate over the counts dict instead of the original word list
# this way each word is only printed once
for word,count in counts.iteritems():
    print word, percent(counts[word],total),"%"
```

Output when run on this program:

```
Total Words
79


text 2.53164556962 %
float 2.53164556962 %
as 1.26582278481 %
file 1.26582278481 %
in 3.79746835443 %
handle 2.53164556962 %
counts 6.32911392405 %
total 3.79746835443 %
open 1.26582278481 %
findall 1.26582278481 %
for 3.79746835443 %
0 1.26582278481 %
percent 2.53164556962 %
formatted 5.06329113924 %
1 1.26582278481 %
re 2.53164556962 %
dict 1.26582278481 %
usr 1.26582278481 %
Words 1.26582278481 %
print 5.06329113924 %
import 1.26582278481 %
split 1.26582278481 %
bin 1.26582278481 %
return 1.26582278481 %
extend 1.26582278481 %
get 1.26582278481 %
python 1.26582278481 %
len 1.26582278481 %
iteritems 1.26582278481 %
part 2.53164556962 %
words 2.53164556962 %
Enter 1.26582278481 %
100 1.26582278481 %
with 1.26582278481 %
count 1.26582278481 %
word 7.59493670886 %
name 2.53164556962 %
read 1.26582278481 %
raw_input 1.26582278481 %
n 3.79746835443 %
r 1.26582278481 %
w 3.79746835443 %
Total 1.26582278481 %
whole 2.53164556962 %
def 1.26582278481 %
```

## Edit -- added explanation of the word formatting

Breakdown of `formatted.extend(re.findall(r'\w+', w))`:

1: the `extend` function of lists takes a list and appends it the given list. For example:

```
listA = [1,2,3]
listB = [4,5,6]
listA.extend(listB)
print(listA)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

2: `re.findall(r'\w+', w))`

This expression uses [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to extract only the part of the string we care about. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) on python's regular expressions.

Basically, `re.findall(x, y)` returns a list of all the substrings in `y` that match the regular expression pattern outlined in `x`. In our case, `\w` means all word characters (i.e. alphanumeric chars), and the `+` means one or more of the preceding pattern. So put together, `\w+` means one or more word characters.

I probably made it somewhat confusing by naming the string variable we're doing the search on `w`, but just keep in mind that the `\w` in the pattern is not related to the `w` variable that is the string.

```
word = 'heres some1; called s0mething!'
re.findall(r'\w+', word)
# ['heres', 'some1', 'called', 's0mething']
```

Comment: check the words like "1print" and "totalprint". They appear because you are replacing `'\n'` with `''` instead of `' '`.

Comment: @chapelo Thanks for noticing. I meant to take out the extraneous `replace()` call since the regular expression gets rid of newlines, but forgot to. Answer has now been updated.

Comment: `formatted.extend(re.findall('\w+', w))`  is there a tutorial for this? I see that it works, but not sure how/why

Comment: @AxilMeeds sure thing. I didn't know whether or not you were familiar with regular expressions. I've edited my answer to included an explanation of that bit.